# Yii2 Pjax do not work properly

Tags: php, yii2, pjax

I have a pjax form in which I should filter book authors by the first letter of their names. But everytime pjax is refreshing the page. There is no errors in the console and can't see an error request in the `network` tab(maybe because of the refreshing just can't see it). After few tests I understood that the probelm is in data line of code `$authorModels = $dataProvider->getModels();`. If I `var_dump` before it it's ok but after this one there is not `var_dump` response. `($authorModels = $dataProvider->getModels();var_dump($authorModels);die;` and the page get refreshed. This is my action:

```
public function actionAuthors(){

$authorsPage = Page::findOne(46);
$banner = CategoryImage::find()->where(['page_id' => 46])->one();
$lang = Lang::getCurrent();
$randomAuthors = Author::find()->where('active=1')->orderBy(new Expression('rand()'))->limit(5)->all();
$randomBooks = Product::find()->where('active=1')->orderBy(new Expression('rand()'))->limit(4)->all();
$bookPage = Page::findOne(45);
$en_arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
$bg_arr = ['а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ж', 'з', 'и', ' й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ю', 'я'];
$array_in_use = [];
$pageSize = 5;

if(Yii::$app->request->isPjax){

    if(isset($_GET['letter']) && $_GET['letter'] != ''){

        $letter = '';
        if($lang->url == "en"){
            $letter = $en_arr[$_GET['letter']];
        }else if($lang->url == "bg"){
            $letter = $bg_arr[$_GET['letter']];
        }

        $sql = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT * 
                                             FROM `author` as a
                                             LEFT JOIN `authorLang` as al ON a.`id`=al.`author_id`
                                             WHERE a.`active`=1 
                                             AND al.`language`='$lang->url'
                                             AND al.`names` LIKE '$letter%'")
                                            ->queryAll();
        $countAuthors = count($sql);

        $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
            'sql' => $sql,
            'totalCount' => $countAuthors,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => $pageSize,
                'route' => Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('first_step')
            ]
        ]);

        $authorModels = $dataProvider->getModels();

        $pagination = new Pagination([
           'totalCount' => $countAuthors,
            'pageSize' => $pageSize,
            'route' => Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('first_step')
        ]);

        return $this->renderPartial('authors', [
            'pagination' => $pagination,
            'authorModels' => $authorModels,
        ]);
    }
}
```

My js:

```
function pjaxFilterForm() {
    var dataString = $("#filter-group2").serialize();
    $.pjax.defaults.timeout = false;
    $.pjax({
        container: "#productGrid",
        url: location.href.split("?")[0],
        data: dataString,
        scrollTo: false
    });
    return false;
}
```

view:

```
<?php
                        ActiveForm::begin([
                            'action' => '#',
                            'method' => 'get',
                            'options' => ['data-pjax' => true, 'onsubmit' => 'return pjaxFilterLetters();', 'id' => 'charsForm',],
                        ]);
                        ?>
                        <input type="hidden" name="letter" />
                        <div class="authors-filter">
                            <ul class="letters">
                            <?php
                                $key = 0;
                                foreach ($array_in_use as $char){
                                    echo "<li value='{$key}'>{$char}</li>";
                                    $key++;
                                }
                            ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
                        <!-- Author Filter -->

                        <!-- Author List -->
                        <?php Pjax::begin(['timeout' => false, 'id' => 'productGrid', 'scrollTo' => false]);?>
                        <ul class="author-list">
                            <li>
                                <?php
                                    if(isset($authorModels) && !empty($authorModels)){
                                        foreach ($authorModels as $author) {
                                            //here are coming the authors
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        echo Yii::t('app', 'app.No authors found');
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Comment: Any reason your not using the Yii2 AR model abstraction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell if it's the only 1 bad thing, but from [Class yii\data\SqlDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-sqldataprovider.html) you can see that `sql` parameters expects string but you're giving an array. Even if you remove `->queryAll()` you will still get an object which is not fine. So, to give string, you can simply write as string, without using `Yii::$app->db->createCommand`:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `author` as a LEFT JOIN `authorLang` as al ON a.`id`=al.`author_id` WHERE a.`active`=1 AND al.`language`='$lang->url' AND al.`names` LIKE '$letter%'";
```

Comment: Thank you! Will try as soon as I get to the laptop :)

Comment: That was the problem! It is fine now. A lot of thanks!